# MAX function in Aurora MySQL 5.6.10a

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, amazon-aurora, sequelpro

I am launching this query using Sequel Pro:

```
select MAX (price) from t_hotel_price group by hotel_id
```

but I got this error

```
FUNCTION hotels.MAX does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

Comment: Try: `select MAX(price) from t_hotel_price group by hotel_id`. See [9.2.4 Function Name Parsing and Resolution :: Built-In Function Name Parsing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html#function-name-parsing).

Comment: please convert to answer !